# Uniformizer $x$ on a curve then $x - x(p)$ uniformizer at all but fin. many points $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is it true that on a projective curve $C$, we have that if $x$ is a uniformizer at some point, then $x - x(p)$ is a uniformizer at $p$ for all but finitely many $p \in C$? If so can u give a proof? Thanks

Comment: Let $x$ be a uniformizer at say $q$. Then, $q$ is a smooth point of $C$ and thus we may assume $C$ is smooth, since the smooth model differs only at finitely many points. Then, $x$ is a non-constant rational function and thus gives a morphism $C\to\mathbb{P}^1$. This has only finitely many points of ramification and for any unramified point $p$, what you say will be true.

Comment: Ok, and how does one know a finite morphism can only have finitely many ramified points?

Comment: In characteristic zero this is immediate by looking at the pull back of a non-zero meromorphic form and it has only finitely many zeroes and poles. In characteristic positive, this is still true since the map is separable because $x$ is uniformizing parameter at one point.